# Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information for parameter "bookpermit"

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to pass multiple parameters dynamically into a route url using @ParamConverter in symfony. Below is my schema structure

```
bookpermit

id | userfk  | bookfk   |
1  | 6       | 6        |
2  | 6       | 7        |
3  | 7       | 7        |
4  | 8       | 8        |
books

id | name  | uerfk   |
1  | xyz1   | 6       |
2  | xyz2   | 7       |
3  | xyz3   | 8       |
```

Below is the snippet of my routing.yml file

```
display_book_by_permission:
    pattern:  /displaybookbypermission/{user}
    defaults: { _controller:  xxxBundle:Books:display, _format: ~ }
    requirements:
        _method: GET
```

I removed the arguments for bookpermit since I want to be fetched dynamically from the database

Below is my controller definition containing the paramconverter

```
 /**
 * @Route("/displaybookbypermission/{user}/{bookpermit}")
 * @ParamConverter("user", class="xxxxBundle:Users")
 * @ParamConverter("bookpermit", class="xxxxBundle:BookPermit")
 * @Template()
 */
public function displayAction(Request $request, $user, $bookpermit)
    {
         $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $bookLists= $em->getRepository("xxxBundle:Books")->findBy(
        array(
            "usersfk" => $user,
            "usersfk" => $bookpermit
        )
    );

    $data = array();

    foreach ($bookLists as $bookList)
    {

        array_push($data, $this->serialize($bookLists));
    }


    $response = new Response(json_encode($data), 200);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return $response;
    }
```

My attempt in doing this is to be able to return this result `xyz2+xyz1` when the url is called

```
http://localhost:88/books/web/app_dev.php/displaybookbypermission/6
```

Comment: first, why are you using both a yml route and an annotation route ? second, in your `bookpermit` table, none of the `bookfk` values refers to `books.id` column. third, `books` table should not contains any reference to user as it looks like the relation between books and users is the `bookmermit` table.

Comment: bookfk refers to (a foreign key to) usersfk in books table. books has a foreign key to user and bookspermit has a foreign key to books called bookfk

Comment: I saw the routing in symfony documentation. Please how can I convert it to yml routing

Comment: We would need some explanations first. this feature represents users, books, and the permission for users to "interact" (rent, read, whatever) with books, right ? what this route is about is to fetch the books the provided user is allowed to interact with, right ?

Comment: very correct from the permission table. so we can say that user with id 6 can only permitted to books by user of 6 and 7

Comment: ok, so clearly your tables are flawed, it's definitely not what they should like like. as stated above, books table should not contains any reference to users. let me few minutes to write an elaborated answer.

Comment: Okay.........................

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161288/discussion-between-float-and-van).

Answer (score 0):

as explained in comments below original post, your feature is about users, books and permissions for users to interact with books.

Then, you should have 3 entities, User, Book, and BookPermit.

here is a minimal model graph we can start with :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Book
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string")
     */
    private $name;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class BookPermit
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="xxxBundle\Entity\User")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="xxxBundle\Entity\Book")
     */
    private $book;

    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function getBook()
    {
        return $this->book;
    }
}
```

next, about the route and the controller :

as stated in comment, you want to use a yaml route, then get rid of your @Route(...) annotation in the controller.

The route is provided a User, and should return a list of books.
So the only param you need is the user. you can typehint the $user parameter with User, so ParamConverter is natively called. And you can simplify how you return the response, using JsonResponse.

The route (nothing to change) :

```
display_book_by_permission:
    pattern:  /displaybookbypermission/{user}
    defaults: { _controller:  xxxBundle:Books:display, _format: ~ }
    requirements:
        _method: GET
```

The controller :

```
use xxxBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

/**
 * @Template()
 */
public function displayAction(Request $request, User $user)
{

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $permits = $em->getRepository("xxxBundle:BookPermit")->findBy(array(
        "user" => $user,
    ));

    $books = array();

    foreach ($permits as $permit) {
        array_push($books, $permit->getBook());
    }

    $response = new JsonResponse($books, 200);

    return $response;
}
```

maybe you'll have some things to correct, but this is the main idea.